# Android Studio: Is it possible to automatically upload images from Gallery?

Tags: image, android-studio, gallery

I am hoping to automatically display selected images from Gallery, but I have no luck to find how to automatically display images from Gallery without any selection from users. (In other words, users will simply see the selected images displayed in the screen rather than seeing Gallery to select images to see.)
Thank you for your help and time in advance!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android upload image from gallery to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770122/android-upload-image-from-gallery-to-server)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It seems the following code asks the user to select images:


startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select file to upload "), req_code);